# Meaning of ₵ symbol on guitar sheet music

Tags: guitar, notation, sheet-music

I have the following sheet music excerpt for Spanish guitar:

[image: Odeon. Tango Brasileiro]

What is the meaning of the ₵2 and C3 on the 2nd and 4th measures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't seen those symbols in that context before, but they must mean that you use your first finger to barre the indicated fret (fret 2 in the second half of the first bar, and fret 3 in the third bar).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Barring the fret is the easiest way to hit the chords in the first chord. I suppose the crossed C indicates half barre (strings E,B,G) and the uncrossed C indicates a full barre.

Comment: @RenanGemignani: Yes, smart that you figured out the half vs the full barre; I'm sure that's the difference between those two symbols.

Comment: The C with a slash through it is also noted as 1/2 C, e.g. 1/2 C5 is a partial barre in the 5th position.

Answer (score 7):

The symbols in question represent in fact barre chords. The numerals following the C indicates the position (i.e., fret) of the barre chord. As OP already has figured out, ₵ refers to a partial barre chord—it does, however, not indicate how many strings should be barred.

A nice overview of the many different styles to notate barre chords is given in the respective [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barre_chord#Notation).

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: The notation rarely spoonfeeds yo by telling you how many strings to bar